# Hide element without overflow

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How to detect if loaded page has overflow/scroll?
I would like to hide an element "go to top" button from main page (which has no overflow on most modern mobile devices) and leave it on other pages.

Here is the [page](http://lilianpix.ru/) and screenshot.

[image: Element to hide]

**Thanks in advance for any suggestions**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the `button` by default and try with this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   // Show the buttom here
   $("#button").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('body').height()>window.innerHeight)
{
  $('.btn').css('display','block');
}
else{
  $('.btn').css('display','none');
}
});
```